# How can I go back to ViewController2 from ViewController5 - Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, dismiss

In swift I have `ViewController1`, `ViewController2`, `ViewController3`, `ViewController4` and `ViewController5`, now from `ViewController1`,

I go to ViewController5 by using `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: nil)` like this:

`ViewController1 -> ViewController2 -> ViewController3 -> ViewController4 -> ViewController5`

now I'm on the ViewController5 and I want to dismiss to the ViewController2, I use the `dismiss(animated: true)` and it only get you back 1 step from your current ViewController, so I get on ViewController4.

The question is, how can I go back to ViewController2 from ViewController5?

So when I got back in `ViewController2` and run `dismiss(animated: true)` I'm going back to ViewController1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension UINavigationController {

func popToViewController<Controller : UIViewController>(_ type: Controller.Type){
    guard let vc = viewControllers.compactMap({ $0 as? Controller }).first else { return }
    popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
  } 

}

navigationController?.popToViewController(ViewController.self)
```

Comment: I think, that's the right answer if I'm using UINavigationController, but the problem is, I don't, I just use UIViewControllers connected each other by Storyboard Segue

Comment: You use Unwind segues for that purpose.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjGge-Qzh1I